# osgexport for Blender: Imported meshes impact scene ( possibly the lighting? )

Tags: c++, blender, openscenegraph

Blender Version 2.79

OSG Version: 3.4.0-9

Operating System: Fedora

I have been using Blender's export utility to export obj files and then using osgconv to convert them to osg files. The files are then imported and rendered into a scene that looks like:
[Image of the working scene before using the export tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0T1B.png)

Today I installed osgexport by Cedric Pinson ( Github page: https://github.com/cedricpinson/osgexport ) to directly export from Blender to osgt files. I get the following results when I import those files and render them.
[Image of the scene where everything goes dark and the lighting is wierd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spjFo.png)

Additional Details:

- The code is set to follow the human character. The rest of the scene
  is static.
- When I use the old human model I get the working effect,
  but the whole purpose of using the converter is to be able to export
  its animations.

Any ideas? I saw the effect and I don't really even know where to start. The only difference is the outputted file from the converter. Everything else is the same. Also, if there is a newer/better way to export blender files into files that OSG can read, then I'm open to any and all suggestions.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, the OSG forum/mailing list is usually pretty good about answering questions, and I believe I've seen Cedric's name there regularly, along with all the main contributors: http://forum.openscenegraph.org/

New users usually have to have their questions go through moderation, to cut down on spam, so just have some patience.

On this specific question, I have 3 suggestions:

1. Convert both files to osgt and run a diff. Ignore any numerical differences, look for things like node arrangement, material types, etc.
2. Try opening your exported model in osgviewer, just to see how the default settings display it. You can also easily play with things like backfaces, lighting settings, clipping planes, before dropping it into your application - press h to see all the run-time options.
3. Instantiate your light with all 3 types of lighting enabled. Particularly, I have found some models depend heavily on specular lighting, but some of the examples don't turn it on. Of course, if you use the full-white values shown here, you may oversaturate, but this is for an example:

   ```
   osg::Light *light = new osg::Light;
   light->setAmbient(osg::Vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0));
   light->setDiffuse(osg::Vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0));
   light->setSpecular(osg::Vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0));  // some examples don't have this one
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much, Ruan. I'm working through your suggestions and here is what I am seeing:

Comment: Thank you very much, Ruan. I'm working through your suggestions and here is what I am seeing:

1. I have converted both files to osgt's and run a diff. Basically, the files are very different. They're so different it is like comparing apples to fish. I used a very simple object ( pretty much just a cube with a color for a texture ). I'm still sorting out the differences to figure out what matters and what does not.

2. I opened the broken models in osgviewer and they all have that weird dark appearance.

3. I am working on number 3 next.

Comment: I just attempted the 3rd suggestion and it didn't have any effect. I already had set the specular to different values. So, I changed them to the values that you suggested, but it didn't change anything. It looks like the issue is in the osg file itself. I'm continuing to analyze the differences.

Comment: Still working on this, but I wanted to give an update. The export from blender also exported a Lamp and a Camera. This is what made the scenery very dark. Removing the Lamp ( and the camera ) fixed the scenery, but the human is still experiencing intense light and shadow. I am looking for the attributes that need to be fixed in order to resolve it.

Comment: Done fixing the problem. Removing the lamps from the nodes helped a lot. The exporter seems to also exaggerate the specularity in the model to an extreme. So, I cut down the specular in the models to practically zero and everything now looks as it should.  Thank you again Ruan for getting me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry - I haven't been on SO for a while, glad you were able to solve it.